# Curve a Group of Lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two layers, one *point* type, the other *line*. In *some cases*, a point feature is placed in the middle of two line features which I want to show them as one curvy line.

The way it's shown now (two different line features of the same layer is shown with two different colors):

[image]

The way I want it to show it (notice that the point feature is moved to be placed on the middle of the curve):

[image]

I tried to change the `Symbology` of the line layer to make a curve, but I could not find a way to filter the features so that only the ones with this property are selected. I also think that `Geometry Generator` should be used to change the geometry of the point feature.

Comment: As a first step, you can add an attribute to each point showing if it intersects two or more lines with `case 
 when array_length(array_distinct( overlay_intersects('lines', $id)))>1 then 1
 else 0
end`

Comment: To reproduce your example, you should provide more details - best share a sample of your data. So the point is not at a fixed location and might be moved? What exactly did you try with Geometry generator? You want that for visualization purpose only (style) or you want to get actual geometries?

Comment: The point is fixed. The source is PostgreSQL. It's only for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possibilities to style lines in a curved way: arrows or QGIS expression function `smooth`. The first option probably does better what you want to achieve.

### Using Arrows

Set your line style to arrow and the values for the head to 0 to get a simple line. Check the box next to `Curved arrows`. The line is then shown in a curved style. You need at least three vertices for the line feature. If you have just single segment lines (just start- und end_point), toggle editing and click in the middle of the line to create an additional vertex and move it to where you want the curve to pass through:

*Above, in red the result, how the curved line finally looks like, in green the actual line; below: how to create a new vertex. When you click the mouse to place the vertex (red arrow), the line changes to a curved one:*

[image]

### Using QGIS expression with function `smooth`

Set the line style to Geometry generator and use the epxression `smooth ($geometry, 10)` - you can change the value of `10` to fit your needs. The line will be showed smoothed:

*Actual line in blue, smoothed line in red:*
[image]